# im trying to get the sum of the variables but when i try to get the output the answer says 812 but i want the answer to be 20

Tags: python, concatenation, string-concatenation

```
quilt_width = 8
quilt_length = 12

print("Number of squares you'll need to create a quilt: " +

str(quilt_width) + str(quilt_length))
```

Comment: Surely you need to multiply the numbers

Answer (score 1):

run this  my friend :

```
quilt_width = 8 ;quilt_length = 12
sum_quilt = quilt_width +quilt_length

print("Number of squares you'll need to create a quilt: " + str(sum_quilt))
print("Number of squares you'll need to create a quilt: " + str(quilt_width + quilt_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation of strings causes the numbers as strings to join. In your case, "8" + "12" becomes 812.
You have to add the **integers** and then convert that to string.

The code is as follows:

```
quilt_width = 8 quilt_length = 12

print("Number of squares you'll need to create a quilt: " + str(quilt_width + quilt_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember the function `str` converts a numeric variable into a  text which we call string in python.

and adding two variables of `string` type will perform a concatenation. when you want to perform arithmetic operations you need to make sure the type of the variable is a number.

```
quilt_width = 8 #this is a number (integer)
quilt_length = 12 #this is a number (integer)
str(quilt_width) + str(quilt_length) # You are converting the numbers into text before adding them
```

This results in

```
"812"
```

The code below will return what you are  expecting

```
quilt_width = 8 #this is a number (integer)
quilt_length = 12 #this is a number (integer)
quilt_width + quilt_length # returns 20 as a number
str(quilt_width + quilt_length) # This returns "20" as a string because first you add the numbers and then you convert the result to numbe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Number of squares you'll need to create a quilt: " +

str(quilt_width + quilt_length))
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of squares you would need to multiply the width by its length:

```
quilt_width = 8
quilt_length = 12

print(f"Number of squares you'll need to create a quilt: {quilt_width * quilt_length}")
```

**Output:**

```
96
```